# Different colors for same element in CSS

Tags: css, wordpress, font-awesome

I've added this to my home page to change the color of Fontawesome Arrow icon to black but I've another arrow on the same page which is an arrow that needs to be white in color. What CSS code do I add to make one arrow stay black and another as white displayed on the same page?

```
.page-id-45 a.sf-button.sf-button-has-icon > i {
        font-size: 18px;
        margin-left: 10px;
        vertical-align: -3px;
        color: #333;
    }
```

Comment: Please post the HTML as well :)

Comment: Learner here. I'm using WordPress here. If you could guide me on how to do that :)

Comment: Can you add another class to this colored icon?

Comment: Why don't you add inline style or add a class defining the color to that particular icon?

Answer (score 0):

If you add ~ i it should apply the color to all but the first arrow.

```
.page-id-45 a.sf-button.sf-button-has-icon > i {
    font-size: 18px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    vertical-align: -3px;
    color: #fff; /* Color of the first arrow of you page */
}
.page-id-45 a.sf-button.sf-button-has-icon > i ~ i {
    font-size: 18px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    vertical-align: -3px;
    color: #333; /* Color of all other arrows */ 
}
```

It's more like a quick fix then a good solution.

Answer (score -1):

You can put your `<class=""><style="color: 000;">` in the HTML; the inline style should override the class colour.

If you're doing it often, I'd suggest a second class.